# Hello everyone! I can’t figure out how to properly refactor my code. I want to make a list of widgets through an array, how to do it right?

Tags: listview, dart, refactoring

My widget looks like this

```
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    Widget _bottomNavigationMenu() {
      return Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(bottom: 30.0),
        child: Wrap(
          crossAxisAlignment: WrapCrossAlignment.end,
          alignment: WrapAlignment.spaceAround,
          spacing: 18.0,
          runSpacing: 20.0,
          children: <Widget>[
            BottomMenuBtn(
              nameIcon: "assets/icons/gps.png",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/locationhistory');
              },
              textBtn: "Location history",
            ),
            BottomMenuBtn(
              textBtn: "Email",
              nameIcon: "assets/icons/mail.png",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/email');
              },
            ),
            BottomMenuBtn(
              textBtn: "Social Media",
              nameIcon: "assets/icons/social.png",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/socialmedia');
              },
            ),
            BottomMenuBtn(
              textBtn: "Screen Time",
              nameIcon: "assets/icons/screen.png",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/screentime');
              },
            ),
            BottomMenuBtn(
              textBtn: "Activity report",
              nameIcon: "assets/icons/activity.png",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/activity');
              },
            ),
            BottomMenuBtn(
              textBtn: "Calls",
              nameIcon: "assets/icons/call.png",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, '/calls');
              },
            ),
          ],
        ),
      );
    }
```

I want to get something like this--->
**create list?**

I try to parse the list of buttons through the map method so as not to observe such a huge amount of code.

How to map this list correctly? maybe i need something else?

```
.....
children: <Widget> [
bottomMenuLists.map((item) => {
 **what write here?**
 *BottomMenuBtn(item)* incorrect
})
]
....
```

**Thanks to everyone who responds!**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let us assume you have a class called `BottomMenuInfo` as follows.

```dart
class BottomMenuInfo {
  String label;
  String imagePath;
  String route;

  BottomMenuInfo({this.label, this.imagePath, this.route});
}
```

Then you populate the list `bottomMenuLists` as you mentioned in the question with above information such as `label`, `imagePath` and `route`.

Finally you can iterate through this map and create the `BottomMenuBtn` widget and return it as a list as shown below.

```dart
children: 
  bottomMenuLists.map((BottomMenuInfo item) {
    return BottomMenuBtn(
              textBtn: item.label,
              nameIcon: item.imagePath,
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, item.route);
              },
            )
  }).toList()
```

Comment: Great it works too!!!I am new and studying, now you have opened my eyes to new chips !! THANKS !!

Answer (score 0):

If you want to make your code briefer, you will need to abstract the common code so it only occurs once, and then supply the varying data in one way or another.

Abstraction of code is generally the job of helper functions.

One possibility would be:

```dart
BottomMenuBtn _makeButton(String text, String iconName, String pushAction) =>
    BottomMenuBtn(
              textBtn: text,
              nameIcon: "assets/icons/$iconName.png",
              onPressed: () {
                Navigator.pushNamed(context, pushAction);
              });
```

Then you can use it to create buttons like:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          ...
          children: <Widget>[
            _makeButton("Location history", "gps", "/locationhistory"),
            _makeButton("Email", "mail", "/email"),
            ...
            _makeButton("Calls", "calls", "/calls"),
          ],
       ...
```

Instead of a list of objects holding these three data-points, and then iterating the list to create another list, the helper function allows you to write the data where it's used (better locality) and with very little syntactic overhead.

The only situation where I'd do something else is when the data is not known at compile-time. So, if someone was passing me a list of

```dart
class _MenuButtonInfo {
  final String text;
  final String iconName;
  final String pushAction;
  _MenuButtonInfo(this.text, this.iconName, this pushAction);
}
```

then I'd use a list literal like:

```dart
Widget build(BuildContext context) {
          ...
          children: <Widget>[
            for (var info in buttonInfos) BottomMenuBtn(
                textBtn: info.text,
                nameIcon: "assets/icons/${info.iconName}.png",
                onPressed: () {
                  Navigator.pushNamed(context, info.pushAction);
                })
          ],
       ...
```

Comment: I am new and studying, now you have opened my eyes to new chips !! THANKS !!